# Выбор NoSQL с моделью данных key-value для работы в .NET

Tags: c#, nosql

Провожу обзор NoSQL баз с моделью данных **key-value** для работы под платформой .Net, а именно C#.

Основными критерии выбора для себя определил следующие:

1. Возможность одновременно писать из нескольких потоков .
2. Наличие механизма транзакций.
3. Максимальная скорость записи/чтения.
4. Наличие работы работы под ОС Windows, Linux(mono).
5. Персистентность(долговечность) хранения данных.

Объем хранимых данных небольшой, порядка 1-5 Gb. Данные записываются и через некоторое время удаляются(временный буфер).

Какие хранилища кто использует?
Какую базу NoSQL лучше выбрать для использования?

Comment: Вроде, [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) подходит под описание.

Comment: Транзакций в K/V хранилищах как правило нет

Comment: Никто не имел дело с [DBReeze](http://dbreeze.codeplex.com)?